# Problems with adding prime numbers in C++

Tags: c++

My code works for numbers up to 300 or 20. But it doesn't work for 2000000. I tried using long instead, but it still didn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
bool prime(int i) {
    bool result = true;
    int isitprime = i;

    for (int j = 2; j < isitprime; j++) { ///prime number tester
        if (isitprime % j == 0) {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    using namespace std;
    long sum = 0;

    for (long i = 2; i <= 2000000; i++) {
        if (prime(i)) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }

    cout << sum << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? (probably, this is the most frequently asked question after "what have you tried")

Comment: What's the problem you are trying to solve, btw?

Comment: Look like you are trying to print the sum of prime numbers upto a certain value. I may be wrong but I'm guessing that this number is too big for your `sum` variable. I suggest you use a large integer library such as GMP.

Comment: @Acorbe the sum of the first prime numbers less than 2 million.

Comment: It appears this code tries to sum all primes from `1` to `N`.

Comment: looks like an overflow of `sum` try `unsigned int64_t` to be totally sure. Also to test if a number is prime it's enough to iterate till `sqrt(isitprime)`, it will save you some computation time

Comment: you should also skip even guys..

Comment: Yes, I am trying to find the sum of all primes below 2000 000

Comment: @Boom_mooB There is an optimization `for (int j = 2; j * j < isitprime; j++)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that the sum of primes less than 2000000 is 142913828922 but the maximum value of a long integer is 2147483647 which is not large enough to store this sum.

Comment: As the comments above suggest, consider using a 64 bit integer to store the sum